# Sonarqube 5.6: SonarQubeFxCop-cs.ruleset does not exist

Tags: sonarqube

I'm not getting any violations when scanning a decent size codebase. The code is scanned, source gets uploaded to the Sonarqube server, but no violations are reported.

System Info
Sonarqube 5.6
Jenkins 1.651.3 with Sonarqube Plugin for Jenkins 2.4.3
Build Slave is Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2015 Update 2

I've created a Quality Profile which inherits the **Sonarqube Way for C#**. No other changes have been made to this profile.

In the jenkins build, I do the following:

1. Sonarqube Scanner for MSBuild - Begin Analysis
2. Build the solution
3. Sonarqube Scanner for MSBuild - End Analysis

When I look at Sonarqube after the build has succeeded, I can see LOC, comment density, duplication, but no bugs, vulnerabilities, or code smells. It's a fairly large project so I expected something.

When I look at the console log in Jenkins I'm seeing a bunch of these:

OverrideCodeAnalysisProperties:
  Skipping FxCop analysis: the SonarQube ruleset does not exist. Ruleset: C:\dev-windeploy-1\workspace\ci-build.sonarqube\conf\SonarQubeFxCop-cs.ruleset

I looked at the conf directory and I'm only seeing the following files:

- SonarLint.xml
- SonarQubeAnalysisConfig.xml
- SonarQubeRoslyn-cs.ruleset

I've tried several searches for this problem, but Sonarqube has made a lot of changes in the Visual Studio area, and most of the results are for older versions of Sonarqube and many of the properties have been deprecated.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!